Do transistors "prefer" to pull current from their base or collector?
The circuit below is a simple BJT amplifier which behaves exactly as expected:

If I remove the capacitive coupling and voltage divider bias and replace it with an input offset, it completely breaks the circuit.
This is perplexing, because I've biased the input (base) to 1.86 V, the exact value that was the DC operating point of the first circuit.

Why does the second circuit fail?
In the spirit of this site,before posting it, I tried to answer it myself, and observed that at the operating point:

The first (working) circuit draws only 11uA from the base, presumably because of the 2k+ input impedance, but over 1 mA from the collector.
The second (failing) circuit draws over a mA from the base, and close to 2mA from the collector.

This suggests to me the following, which I ask is this correct:

Even with a high beta, if current can flow through the base, it will.  To get the vast majority of the current from the collector, which is needed for this type of amplifier, it is not enough to have a high beta.  You also need to limit the current through the base.

Adding a base resistor to the second circuit seemed to fix it, which supports my hypothesis.
That is: Transistors will take almost all of their current from the collector if they must, but if more current is available from the base, they'll do that.
I believe that is correct, but it's certainly not very precise.  Is that correct? What is a more precise way of stating this?

Vbase for the second circuit isn't a sine wave with 1.86V DC.  It has more like 3.7 V DC on it.

It would have been instructive to look at V(base) in the first circuit. Then you could compare apples to apples with the second circuit.
The problem is not that the transistor "prefers" to get current from the base. It's that you're starving the collector for current, and therefore the transistor is saturated for most of the cycle. The collector voltage basically follows the base voltage — the big clue being that the output is in-phase with the input for most of the cycle, rather than being inverted. It only comes out of saturation briefly at the bottom of the cycle, and then it works normally, inverting the negative peak for a short time.

"It's that you're starving the collector for current, and therefore the transistor is saturated for most of the cycle."  I do not understand this sentence - can you please explain further?

If you apply 4 V to the base, that means that there will be about 3.3 V across the emitter resistor (R4 in your second diagram), and it will have 3.3 mA flowing through it. However, if you try to draw this current through the collector resistor (R3), the voltage drop across it would be 9.9 V, far greater than the available supply. The actual collector voltage is about 0.4 V below the base voltage, so there's only about (9 - 3.6)/3k = 1.8 mA available there, and the rest of the emitter current must necessarily flow from the base.

The term "saturation" basically refers to any time the collector voltage is less than the base voltage.
